# Filling sides of a centered div?

Tags: css, layout, html, multiple-columns

I want to fill the sides of a centered div with another div or span on each side.

I'm using margining to center the div as shown in this [fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/D738a/3/)

**HTML**

```
<div id='A>
  <div id='Ad'>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#A{
  z-index: 3000;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height:  40px;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
}

/*
div or span to the left
*/

/*
centered div
*/
#Ad{
  z-index: 3000;
  width:  400px;
  height:  40px;
  margin-left:  auto;
  margin-right:  auto;
  border-left: solid 1px #ff0000;
  border-right: solid 1px #ff0000;
}

/*
div or span to the right
*/
```

How can I have a div that always takes up the remaining space on the left and another div that takes up the remaining space on the right.

**Clarification:**

Center column needs to be constant width.  Left and Right Columns vary with the window size.

Comment: Is there a reason not to use 3 `<div>s` in the main container?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would achieve what you want - it allows you to have a fixed width central div with left and right columns that fill up the remaining space:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="A">
    <div id="Ad">Centre</div>
    <div id="left">Left</div>
    <div id="right">Right</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#A {
    z-index: 3000;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
/*
centered div
*/
 #Ad {
    z-index: 3000;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border-left: solid 1px #ff0000;
    border-right: solid 1px #ff0000;
}
#left, #right {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    right:50%;
    margin-right:200px;
    background:#F00;
    height: 400px;
}
#right {
    left:50%;
    right:0;
    margin-left:200px;
    margin-right:0;
}
```

The key is that the margin on the left/right is half of the central column's total width, so adjust it to take into account any borders or padding.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/2AztF/

Comment: ...nice but Jon's solution is much simpler, any comparisons?

Comment: It is.  To be honest floating is the most common solution but as Jon got there before be I thought I would offer a different perspective as this is more appropriate in certain situations (for instance where you want the left and right columns to sit outside of the parent rather than the parent being the full width of all 3).

Comment: And of course Jon's solution makes your central column variable width, which might not be suitable.  This solution lets your central column stay fixed while keeping the other two elastic.

Comment: ..snap I just noticed that...can't have the center column changing width like that.

Comment: Your central column is 400px wide.  I position the left column 50% right and divide the central width by 2.  Technically it should be 201px due to the 1px border.

Comment: If you use something like lesscss.org you can easily automate this by making a variable for the central column width and basing the margin on this.

Comment: In the real app, I'm using 1000px center, If I add 500px on each side, this will cause the page to be too wide, i.e. the horizontal scroller will appear.

Comment: Try it - the 500px margin would overlap the 1000px central column so that the column actually starts on the edge.

Comment: I'll take your word and try next chance I get.

Comment: Just for your ease of mind, here is a working example with a 1000px central column: http://jsfiddle.net/2AztF/1/

Answer (score 1):

I would just use 3 `<div>s` floated within the main container

**HTML:**

```
<div id='A'>
  <div id='AdLeft'></div>
  <div id='Ad'></div>
  <div id='AdRight'></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#A { overflow:auto }
#AdLeft { float:left; width:25%; }
#Ad { float:left; width:50%; }
#AdRight { float:left; width:25%; }
```

Here is a modified [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D738a/5/).

Answer (score 1):

To fill space on the right and left side of your div code use and make sure you have no margin or padding on those sides.

```
float:right; 
float:left;
```

HTML:

```
<div class='container'> 
<div class='left'></div> 
<div class='center'></div>
<div class='right'></div> 
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container { overflow: hidden; margin:0; padding:0; }
.right { float: right; width: 150px; }
.center{ float: right; width:50px; margin-right: 50px; }
.left{ float: left; width: 150px; }
```

The margin-right of .center will fill the space accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Make 3 divs :

```
<div id="A"></div>
<div id="B"></div>
<div id="C"></div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

CSS:

```
 #A,#B,#C{
    float:left;
    width:10%;
  } 
  #B{
    width:80%;
  }
```

Here, B is you main div.
It is good practice to clear when you use float property.

Comment: I need the center div a constant width.

Comment: just replace the (x)% w/ a (x)px ?